# Magento 2: Media url issue url like "example.com/media/a.png" not working

Tags: magento2, apache2

I migrated my website from nginx to apache, my media url of nginx are not working now.

For example below url used to work earlier

```
example.com/pub/media/blog-banner.jpg
example.com/media/blog-banner.jpg
```

But after migration only `pub/media` one work : example.com/pub/media/blog-banner.jpg

can you tell what should i do to fix issue

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be running the following command within your Magento Root:

```
ln -s pub/media media
```

This command will create a symlink for media to pub/media so the old links will still work.